# CKEditor 4 shortcode replacement

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, shortcode

I'm trying to make a shortcode "plugin" - similar to what Wordpress uses with TinyMce. I'd like user to be able to insert a shortcode (like `[gallery id="3"]` or `[image id="9"]`) via a button and then show a placeholder instead of the actual shortcode. I'll put all the code to github once I get it to work.

## Current setup

I have a button which inserts html to the editor using `insertHtml()` like this:

```
// Custom button code
CKEDITOR.instances['editor_instance_name'].insertHtml '<div class="media-library-gallery">[gallery id=' + gallery_id + ']</div>'
```

and I've added `extraAllowedContent` to allow `div` with the classes I need:

```
// CKEditor configuration (config.js)
config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(media-library-image,media-library-gallery)';
```

I managed to replace `div.media-library-gallery` with an image using the code below:

```
(function() {
  CKEDITOR.plugins.add('media_gallery', {

    init: function(editor) {
      CKEDITOR.addCss('.media_gallery{background: #f2f8ff url("/assets/gallery.png") no-repeat scroll center center; border: 1px dashed #888; display: block; width:100%; height: 250px;}');
    },

    afterInit: function( editor ) {
      var dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor;
      var dataFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.dataFilter;

      dataFilter.addRules({
        elements: {
          'div': function(element) {
            if (element.attributes.class == "media-library-gallery") {
              var fakeElement = editor.createFakeParserElement(element, 'media_gallery', 'div', false);
              return fakeElement;
            }
          }
        }
      })

    }

  })
})();
```

## The problem

Currently the replacement nests a div inside the paragraph tag:

```
<p>
  <div class="media-library-gallery">[gallery id="5"]</div>
</p>
```

[image: Shortcode replacement bug]

I don't want to change the `enterMode` from the default `CKEDITOR.ENTER_P` but I want to get rid of the surrounding `p`. Can I do this using `insertHtml` or write a rule that would do that for me? Any other suggestions are welcome.

I've been digging around http://docs.ckeditor.com/ for a solution/inspiration but had little luck.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but try to insert your div as an element:

```
var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('<div class="media-library-gallery">[gallery id=' + gallery_id + ']</div>');
CKEDITOR.instances['editor_instance_name'].insertElement(element);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to try this out; I'm not even sure which project I wanted to try this on :) I hope someone else comes across this post and reports if your suggestion works.